# When editing files on a (Windows?) networked drive I get "could not be saved" errors

Tags: macos, autosave, network-user

When I edit files that are stored locally, everything works fine, but when editing files that are stored on my networked home directory (at uni here), I get:

```
The document "<x>" could not be saved.
```

when I try to save a file. If I then close the program (XCode), I get this:

[image: Error1]

If I click duplicate, and then reopen the file, the changes I just made are all there. And as far as I can tell, no duplicate file is created. With TextEdit I get this:

[image: Error2]

I've lost the browser tab now, but I read something that was saying this will only happen for programs that use OSX's autosave feature or something? So far, I get the error message in XCode and TextEdit, but not TextWrangler.

The networked drive is at `/Volumes/Student/Home/myUsername/`, and I *think* it's a windows drive, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT:**
As requested, `df`:

```
Filesystem                             512-blocks       Used   Available Capacity  iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                           1951845952   92568016  1858765936     5% 11635000  232345742    5%   /
devfs                                         363        363           0   100%      629          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                                      0          0           0   100%        0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                                   0          0           0   100%        0          0  100%   /home
map -fstab                                      0          0           0   100%        0          0  100%   /Network/Servers
//myUsername@domain.edu.au/student        285149176   74120992   211028184    26%        0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/student
//myUsername@domain.edu.au/student/Home 17203089400 5130812464 12072276936    30%        0 18446744073709551615    0%   /Volumes/student/Home
```

, and `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Comment: Next time you are at the computer, capture `df` and `diskutil list` in case that helps explain what paths are mounted to which shares and drives.

Comment: @bmike Added to question.

Answer (score 1):

Autosave is not working, you might not have sufficient permission on that volume. You should try rebuild the permissions or take the folder ownership using `chown -R`.

"… does not support permanent storage" means Versions is not working because the volume is not HFS+, it must be NTFS or FAT and you are using a protocol such as smb.

Apps who aren't using Version and Autosave have no problems.
If you want to disable these look [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/11/disable-auto-save-and-versions-in-mac-os-x/).